# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk17/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, java-17

I don't understand what went wrong with me. I'm trying to run Spigot Server Core 1.18.2, and I'm constantly having problems with this library.

> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk17/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2389)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:285)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1388)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1386)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1385)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1423)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.(Toolkit.java:1397)
> [19:21:50 INFO]: [STDERR]:      at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.(Component.java:624)

Comment: This exception has to do with either a missing library or a classpath issue when running code that has already been compiled successfully

Comment: does the file _/opt/jdk17/lib/libawt_xawt.so_ exist and is readable by the user that executes the java program? (For a service this could be a different user than your own)
Does the file _libXrender.so.1_ exist? (probably in the same directory, but could anywhere in the java library path specified with the system property _java.library.path_)

Answer (score 8):

This problem seems to stem from Java attempting to load GUI-related classes in non-gui environment, like headless server. Perhaps adding
 `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to java command would help, if the application supports that, and does not in fact require to run in Desktop environment.

Comment: I got that error when running mvn build on wsl- ubuntu. your solution works but is there a permanent solution?

Comment: @Ajeetkumar it's not clear to me what's the root cause of your problem. The permanent solution may be to add the flag to your build command as much as to upgrade you stack - recent versions of Windows, for example, handle GUI apps natively, and should not cause this error - as long as you access the WSL console within desktop session.

Comment: had the same error on a bungeecord proxy. This solution worked!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late for this, but what worked for me was:

`apt-get install libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386`

Comment: I had a this error, though in my case I was on WSL Ubuntu 22.04 and had recently done `wsl --update`.
A maven plugin suddenly started complaining about missing/unlinked libs.
I had to `apt-get install` the following packages: `libxrender1, libxtst, libxtst6, libxi6`

Comment: the comment here worked for me on wsl2 except libxtst wasn't found so I just did the others and it seems to be working.